# Feature importance for xgboost

Tags: importance, boosting

I'm using [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) (extreme gradient boosted trees) for binary classification.  I'd like to calculate feature importance scores, to help me understand the relative importance of different features.  The XGBoost library supports three methods for calculating feature importances:

- "weight" - the number of times a feature is used to split the data across all trees.  (also called f-score elsewhere in the docs)
- "gain" - the average gain of the feature when it is used in trees.
- "cover" - the average coverage of the feature when it is used in trees.

That's the entire description given in the documentation.  After doing some research, I think "gain" is the information gain, and I don't know what "cover" is.

How should I choose among these different methods of calculating feature importance? In my setting, the features are one-hot encodings of categorical data, so all features are zero-or-one values.   Is one superior to others, in this setting?  I'd like to make sure that whatever method I use is statistically well-grounded and is not 'voodoo'.

Comment: Theres no statistically correct way to do this kind of thing. Feature importance is not something the model is measuring about nature, it is something the human is measuring about the fit model. Which of these is appropriate is dependent on how you, the human, want to use the information.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, fair enough!  Are there any guidelines to approach that decision?  How I want to use it: I want to gain some kind of "understanding" about the model, so it is not just a magic black box.  One way to gain some understanding is to get a feeling for which features are having the biggest impact on classification decisions.

Comment: There is an R tool called "Boruta" which is used to compute variable importance.  One of its options is "getImpXgboost" (link)[https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Boruta/versions/7.0.0/topics/getImpXgboost] It seems to do what you are looking for.  If you had toy data to test, then I could show you how it works, and what it does.

Comment: @EngrStudent, ok, I list 3 options, and you've offered a 4th option.  The question I want to know is: how should I choose among these 3 or 4 options?

Comment: @D.W. - there are a couple directions to figure out how you go about choosing: top-down, bottom-up, or sideways.  Top-down is first principles.  Lots of folks here love that.  Many problems are hard or impossible.  Many solutions are intractable enough to be inaccessible without a degree.  Bottom-up is data driven.  Can you give an example of your problem, and we can hit that rock with tools until one of them breaks it?  You could look at the peer-reviewed published papers that describe in agonizing detail how it works.  That is sideways because you don't derive nor test.